# SQL SELECT statement with symbol or text

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get data from my database. I have no problems with this, the SELECT statement works fine, but I want to select the record with a symbor or text before the result.

When I run the code:

```
SELECT price
FROM products
WHERE id = "1"
```

Ill get `5.00`. But in this case I want to select it with a "€" symbol before the price. I found some scripts on this site where they are using the following code:

```
SELECT "€ " + price as 'price'
FROM products
WHERE id="1"
```

When I run this i get the same result as in the first code. So my question is: How can I select the `price` from the database with a symbol or text before (or after) the result?

Comment: What is your RDBMs ?

Comment: Different RDBMs have different ways to concatenate strings

Comment: First of all you should format values on  the client side. But if you really want to do it on SQL server side then cast numbers to strings `SELECT '€ ' + cast(price as varchar) as "price"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified what is your RDBMs your answer is:

```
SELECT CONCAT('€ ', price) as price
  FROM products
 WHERE id=1
```

Don't use double quotes to use strings, double quotes on SQL is to name things like columns as alias and only use it when you want a field named with characters that the database wouldn't allow it like `"Column name with spaces"`

Also, `ID` is probably a number, so no need to use quotes since it will imply in implicit conversion which will make your query slower.

Comment: Jorge, If the price for ID is empty I get as result `€`. How can I write this code so it will only show the currency (or text) if there is a result

Comment: I dont want to show the `€` if there is no price in `id=1`

Comment: You can use a  `CASE` statement, it would be something like: `CASE price IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('€ ', price) ELSE '' END as price`